# devenv deployment for SSIS package on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, command-line

I am trying to deploy SSIS package (package.dtsx) to sql database server running on windows using the visual studio devenv.exe as below

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com' pro.sln /deploy /pr
oject ".\pro\pro.dtproj" /projectconfig "Release"
```

it does not work, throws usage error, not sure what is wrong here,  Is there any way to pass the server name, database name, to the command?

Comment: Have you looked into the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages

Comment: Looked into the documentation, did not find deployment parameters, or examples for deploy option for SSIS server catalog

Comment: devenv is used to build your SSIS solution, ISDeploymentWizard is used to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Deployment to SSIS worked with below command:

ISDeploymentWizard.exe /Silent /SourcePath:"C:project.ispac" /DestinationServer:"servername" /DestinationPath:"/SSISDB//pro"